# which one is idiomatic? 1. Jim is confused 2. Alice and her sister are confused

Tags: word-usage

It sounds like the tutorial is saying (a video link with a time stamp)

> the
>   first thing I want to show you is that
>   one of the reasons why these verbs are
>   so frequently **confused**

where **confused** is in the form of passive voice.

confuse has [this meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confuse)

> Someone who confuses one thing with another thinks the first thing is the second

I rewrote the example in cambridge dictionary as

> Jim is confusing Alice with her sister – she’s the one who moved to Colorado

## question

which one in the following is idiomatic? (maybe both are)

1. Jim is confused
2. Alice and her sister are confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of your sentence about Jim, neither (1) nor (2) mean the same  thing.

*Jim is confused* means that he is muddled in his thinking (either about a particular issue, or in general), and *Alice and her sister are confused* would be understood to mean the same. It's OK to say *these verbs are confused* because there's no danger of that being understood in the other sense (although you could add *with one another.*)

You could say *Jim has confused Alice with her sister.* or *Alice and her sister are sometimes confused with one another.*

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful. Could I say "Alice and her sister are sometimes confused by Jim"?

Comment: You could, although out of context that sentence could also be taken to mean that they find something about him confusing.